# find Noise level iwlist and iwconfig commands

Tags: wireless

I'm tryng to find out the *noise level*, and the commands below should show the information in the **Quality** lines, but somehow it doesn't show.
Any ideas?

```
iwlist scan
wlp3s0    Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 30:B5:C2:B4:F2:A8
                Channel:11
                Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
         --->   Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Ariel"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                Extra: Last beacon: 499772ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 0005417269656C
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 03010B
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0103FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 331AAD0103FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D160B071700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 34160B071700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101850003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD9B0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700100001020304050607080930B5C2B4F2A91021000754502D4C494E4B1023000A544C2D5744523433303010240003312E3010420003312E301054000800060050F20400011011001A576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57445234333030100800020086103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001

sudo iwconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Ariel"  
        Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 30:B5:C2:B4:F2:A8   
        Bit Rate=144 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
        Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
        Encryption key:off
        Power Management:off
 --->   Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm
        Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
        Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another question similar to this. It looks like this is because of driver capabilities

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232433/iwconfig-does-not-show-noise-level-for-wireless

Answer (score 0):

iw survey:
eg:

```
iw wlan1 survey dump
```

Output is each frequency and has noise:

```
Survey data from wlan1
        frequency:                      2437 MHz [in use]
        noise:                          -105 dBm
        channel active time:            50 ms
        channel busy time:              17 ms
```

Your wifi driver needs to support it, some come out with an empty output